# Using ArUco to synchronize pan/tilt/zoom cameras

Tags: opencv, linear-algebra, rotational-matrices

I start with two pan/tilt/zoom cameras oriented so they can both see an ArUco marker. These cameras have been calibrated to determine the camera matrix, and the size of the marker is known. I can determine the rotation and translation vectors from the marker to each camera, and the cameras' current pan, tilt, and zoom positions are known.

If I move the marker and turn one camera to follow it, I can note the new pan/tilt/zoom position and determine the new rotation and translation vectors. Now I want to turn the second camera to face the marker. How can I determine the new pan and tilt settings required?

I think I understand how to build a combined transformation matrix from the two sets of rotation and translation vectors, but I don't know how to account for changing pan/tilt values.

I put some code in a [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pTcITz1RfHcw2qmgQ2ZepT8RRGrEjex5?usp=sharing) to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: it's all just a bunch of vectors/points in space. you'll deal with 4x4 transformation matrices. this is basically computer graphics, or robotics. you calculate the vector the camera has to look towards, and you establish a few axes and calculate the angles, and map that to your pan/tilt values.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how do I do that. I've been trying to get that to work all week and I can't get the numbers to come out right.

Comment: I would recommend visualizing every step somehow. also naming the matrices sensibly: each should contain the names of both coordinate frames, so you know you're multiplying the correct matrices (like dominos).